# Troubles with simple accumulation with Theano scan function

Tags: theano

I am trying to accumulate matrix values while multiplying with the step: 
res = sum_i(i * a). My code looks like this:

```py
import numpy as np
from theano import function, scan
import theano.tensor as T

x = T.lmatrix()
results, updates = scan(
    lambda res, step, x: res + step * x, 
    non_sequences=x,
    sequences=T.arange(2),
    outputs_info=T.zeros_like(x))

f = function([x], results)
a = np.array([[0, 0], [2, 2]], 'int64')
print(f(a))
```

This outputs:

```
[[[0 0]
  [0 0]]

[[1 1]
 [1 1]]]
```

While I would expect this:

```
[[[0 0]
  [0 0]]

[[0 0]
 [2 2]]]
```

Comment: I've provided an answer that explains why you get the output you actually get but can't comment on why that differs from your expectation because it's not clear *why* you expect the output `[[[0 0]  [0 0]] [[0 0] [2 2]]]`. If you update the question with more information on your expectation, I might be able to update my answer with more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output is (perhaps unsurprising?) correct. The reason you get this output is as follows:

In the first iteration,

```
res = 0
step = [[0, 0], [0, 0]]
x = [[0, 0], [2, 2]]
```

and so

```
res + step * x = 0 + [[0, 0], [0, 0]] * [[0, 0], [2, 2]]
               = 0 + [[0, 0], [0, 0]]
               = [[0, 0], [0, 0]]
```

In the second iteration,

```
res = 1
step = [[0, 0], [0, 0]]
x = [[0, 0], [2, 2]]
```

and so

```
res + step * x = 1 + [[0, 0], [0, 0]] * [[0, 0], [2, 2]]
               = 1 + [[0, 0], [0, 0]]
               = [[1, 1], [1, 1]]
```

Note that the 1 is broadcasted to same shape as the matrix that results from the elementwise multiplication of `step` and `x`.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I now understand my mistake. The order of the parameters in the lambda function was different from what I assumed. It should be `lambda step, res, x: res + step * x`

Comment: It helps to keep the order of the parameters passed to the step function to mirror the order in which those parameter types are passed to the step function. So use `scan(sequences=[...], outputs_info=[...], non_sequences=[...])` since the step function is always given sequences first, then recurrent values (`outputs_info`) second, and non sequences last.